# Пользовательский русский шрифт в iOS 4

Tags: xcode, objective-c, iphone

Здравствуйте.

Как подгрузить и применить пользовательский **русский** шрифт в xcode4? 
В android это делается вполне просто:

1. загружаем фал ttf в проект (рекомендуют в папку `assets/fonts`)
2. применяем данный шрифт:

   ```
   Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/customFonts.ttf");
   final TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
   title.setTypeface(tf);
   ```

Можно ли так же сделать и в xcode4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно работать: [Load and Access Custom Fonts](http://sugartin.info/2011/07/25/load-and-access-custom-fonts/).

Comment: Все работает в версии iOS 4.2 и выше, но в версии 4.1 применение не происходит. Требуется поддержка всех версий iOS включая и 4.1!

Comment: @Alegoruis этот способ работает на iOS 3.2+. Вы точно все правильно делаете?

Comment: Подозреваю, что эта проблема из-за jailbreak, который стоит именно на 4.1. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без info.plist + загружать можно динамически (во время разработки я так точно грузил в т.ч. из папки Documents, а вот с этим финтом ушла прилага в стор или без уже не помню):[Веселые шрифты в своем приложении](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/macosxdev/117179/)

Comment: Спасибо. В ближайшее получу сертификаты и обязательно проверю всю работу.